# Current Induced by A Magnetic Field

Tags: electromagnetism

I will make my question direct and straightforward :
Why moving a coil in a constant magnetic field doesnot induce a current.
If the answer is because the variation of the magnetic field induces the current , i will be grateful if the reason of this fact is explained.

Comment: Do you mean a magnetic field that is uniform throughout space as well as over time?

Comment: Yes exactly , totally uniform magnetic field

Comment: You question contains false and  contradictory statements. Moving a coil in a constant magnetic field, in general, **does induce a current**.

Comment: Specifically, rotating a coil around an axis which is not parallel to the magnetic field (and not a symmetry axis of the coil) does produce an EMF (and induces a current in the coil and any external connected circuitry).  That's how generators work.

Answer (score 0):

The way I imagine how the current is induced is by using Maxwell-Faraday equation:
$$\oint_C {E \cdot d\ell = - \frac{d}{{dt}}} \int_S {B_n dA}$$
 When we vary the flux there appears an electric field along the contour of the surface through which we varied the flux and this electric field drives the electrons (produces current).

Answer (score 0):

You could think of it in terms of Lenz's Law.

Say you have a uniform magnetic field directed downwards and a horizontal loop of wire passing through it let's say towards the north.  If you consider the leading edge of the loop Lenz's law tells us there should be and induced current towards the east that would produce a Lorentz force on the wire to the south  opposing the inducing action.  But, if you consider the trailing edge of the loop there would be and induced current to the east for the same reason.  These two currents are trying to flow in opposite directions *around the loop* so no current actually flows.

On the other hand if, rather than translate the loop of wire, you rotate the loop about a diameter **a current will be induced**.  Say the north most part of the loop is moving up and starting to move south.  Lenz's law predicts a Lorentz force opposing this towards the north produced by an induced current to the east.  The opposite side of the loop will be moving down and north resulting in a induced force to the south and an induced current to the west.  Now you have a situation where the two induced currents are in the same sense around the loop and a current flows.  As Whit3rd pointed out this is the basic design of a generator.